# How to cache listview data in android?

Tags: android, caching, listview

I have a Listview that contains 100 rows. This is the first time I load all the data from a Webservice. I want to cache that data so that if I open that page I should get it from cache not from the Webservice. How can I do this?

Comment: use this example,i just got working it.refer this question.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154164/in-android-how-to-implement-cache-in-listview][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154164/in-android-how-to-implement-cache-in-listview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data is simple enough, just store them in an array and use something like **ArrayAdapter** to bind the data to the list view.

If your data is more complex, then an SQLite table is probably preferable. In this case use something like **SimpleCursorAdapter**.

Answer (score 1):

Save your data in a **SQLite table** and use that as **cache** next time check if that table exists. If the table exists query that in stead of the webz :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can store the data as a [JSON](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=define%3a%20json) file in your application's [internal storage space](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal). I find that this is a much easier approach, as you can easily map the JSON to Model classes using a library like [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).  You would typically follow this approach if the data you have will not be "updated" like you might do in a traditional database(although you are still able to update your JSON data, just differently).

Comment: I would like to know is Internal storage not accessible even if the phone is rooted?

Comment: internal storage should always be available, unless you have no space

Comment: sorry I am not asking that, actually in docs its written that in internal storage are not accessible to other apps and even user I want to know does this condition remains true if  the phone is rooted even?

Comment: i think its safe to say that on a rooted phone, most data will be public to the user unless you have provided some form of encryption to protect it.

Answer (score 0):

im assuming since you use the term cache - the data expires every x mins / hours

if the data changes every few mins simply save your webservice response in some local variable (if it only needs to be used for a single listview activity)

or save it in global variable (extend the application class and expose a public variable from here)

if your data changes every few hours then a better idea is to save it in sqlite (if your data needs complex querying / joins etc etc)

or simply save it as a file (either in json or xml format) and check for this file and expiry and if still valid simply decode it instead of calling your webservice again