# Caching a complex ListView data

Tags: android, caching, android-listview, fileoutputstream, objectoutputstream

I have a `ListView` where each item is made of multiple `TextViews` and `Bitmaps`. The list is quite large and it takes around 5-6 seconds to load when the app is launched. So, I'm trying to cache the `ListView` data into my SD card, so that the list is created only once and after that, the app would read the list from cache, instead of creating the list all over again (I'm using `AsyncTask`).

So, I tried caching `ListView` data as simple `Serializable` object, using `FileOutPutStream` and `ObjectOutputStream`. This works fine for simple lists, but in my case, I'm unable to read data from cache. The stack trace says the object couldn't be read as it is not `Serializable`. How can I store such complex `ListView` data? I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154164/in-android-how-to-implement-cache-in-listview) so far.

Comment: use UIL ( universal image loader ) and enable cache saving on disk, easy use and very powerful library

Comment: It would be easier for us to determine how to improve your performance if you posted your adapter code, and how you load your current data.

Answer (score 0):

You may have done this, but it's not clear as I can't see your code: You have to extend extend `Serializable` in your custom `ListView`, and you'll likely need to set and explicity `serialVersionUID` (at least I did):

```
public class ListView implements Serializable {


    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 21;
```